# Pip enum on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, pip

I have a use for enums. Works fine on Ubuntu, python 2.7

On windows python 2.7  I have loaded Enums using pip

```
pip install enum
```

and

```
pip install Enum
```

When I run the program on Windows:

```
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    A = 0
    B = 1
```

I get the error

> `#` Part of ÔÇÿenumÔÇÖ, a package providing enumerated types for Python.
>   ImportError: cannot import name Enum on line 1

Can anyone help please?

Comment: There are a lot of enum packages on pip and Python 3.4+ includes an enum module.  Need more detail here.

Comment: That enum package seems to offer a different implementation of enum. If you're looking for a backport of python3.4's enum functionality, look into  [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the Enums package is for Python 3 and I am using Python 2.7

For some reason, it works OK on Ubuntu, but not on Windows

So I've resorted to using a dict:

```
Foo = {'A':1, 'B':2, 1:'A', 2:'B'}
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like the Enum package should be used like this

```
Foo = Enum("A","B","C","D",...)
print(Foo.A)
```

that doesnt address your question... but in your example there is no reason at all to use the Enum class

```
class MyEnum(object):
     A = 0
     B = 1

print(MyEnum.A)
```

Comment: This does not give the functionality I'm looking for. I use both Foo['bar'].value and Foo(bar).name